# Invalid files when creating X509 certificates containing extensions with newer versions of PyASN1

Tags: python, x509, asn.1, pyasn1

I have a python script that used to work for generating X509 certificates with certificate extensions using PyASN1 and `pyasn1_modules` modules. But now that I've updated these modules to the latest versions from pypi (previously they were from Ubuntu 14.04 repos), generated certificates are no longer valid (according to `openssl x509` command and also `dumpasn1` command which shows changes from previously generated certificates, notably extension values are no longer wrapped in an `OctetString` container).

This is the problematic code:

```
from pyasn1.type import univ
from pyasn1.codec.der import encoder as der_encoder
from pyasn1_modules import rfc2459

extn = rfc2459.BasicConstraints()
extn.setComponentByName('cA', True)
extn.setComponentByName('pathLenConstraint', 5)

extn_val = der_encoder.encode(extn)
extension = rfc2459.Extension()
extension.setComponentByName('extnID', '2.5.29.19')
extension.setComponentByName('critical', True)
extension.setComponentByName('extnValue', extn_val)
```

I've tried changing last line to this:

```
extension.setComponentByName('extnValue', univ.OctetString(extn_val))
```

Which raises this error from PyASN1:

```
Component value is tag-incompatible: OctetString(hexValue='30060101ff020105') vs Any()
```

What are the changes in recent versions that might have caused this and how can I correct my code to make it compatible with new version of these two modules (and preferably keep it compatible with previous versions).

New versions: pyasn1 0.1.9, and pyasn1_modules 0.0.8

Ubuntu repo versions: pyasn1 0.1.7, and pyasn1_modules 0.0.3

Python version 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably encode the OCTET STRING container as well.

The reason is that RFC specifies it as OCTET STRING, but pyasn1-modules use ANY type for it. Since ANY type is serialized transparently (e.g. no tag added), you need to pass OCTET STRING serialization.

```
extension.setComponentByName('extnValue', der_encoder.encode(univ.OctetString(extn_val)))
```